# Jquery - cannot select the parent div

Tags: jquery, dom

I hope this isn't a waste of time, however I have really been trying to figure this on out. Is it my syntax. I simply want to remove the parent div ".number-row" once the link with a class of ".remove-link" is clicked.

Thanks in advance

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".remove-link").click(function() {
        $(this).parent(".number-row").hide();
    })
})
</script>
```

---

```
<div class="number-row" >
   <div class="number-column">
         <div class="label-row">
             Select Country:
         </div>
         <div class="input-row">
             <select>
                 <option>1</option>
                 <option>2</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="label-row">
             Select Toll Free or City:
         </div>
         <div class="input-row">
             <select>
                 <option>1</option>
                 <option>2</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="label-row">
             Select Your Number:
         </div>
         <div class="input-row">
             <select>
                 <option>1</option>
                 <option>2</option>
             </select>
         </div>
     </div>
   <div class="number-column">
         <div class="label-row">
             Select Country:
         </div>
         <div class="input-row">
             <select>
                 <option>1</option>
                 <option>2</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="label-row">
             Enter Number to Forward to:
         </div>
         <div class="input-row">
            <input type="text" name="forward_number" id="forward_number" />
         </div>
         <div class="number-row-options">
            <a class="save-link" href="#">Save</a>
            <a class="remove-link" href="#">Remove</a>
         </div>                    
     </div>                    
</div>
```

Comment: the div does not have a parent with class "number-row"

Comment: @Sleepyhead: it has an ancestor; common bit of confusion between the behavior of parent() and parents().

Answer (score 7):

Try [parents()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parents) instead of [parent()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".remove-link").click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".number-row").eq(0).hide();
    })
})
```

Comment: I usually do a slice(0, 1) as well to just get the closest matching parent, though with a such specific selector it might not be that important..

Answer (score 2):

This should do it...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".remove-link").click(function() { 
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    }) 
})
```

Note that this doesn't **remove**, which you requested; it simply **hides** it.  You can use `remove()` instead of `hide()` to remove it from the DOM.